# ChartConfiguration missing 'time' parameter in 'options.scales.x'

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm updating from chartjs 2.9.4 to 3.8.0 and I'm getting an error setting `options.scales.x.time.unit` parameter on an `ChartConfiguration` object.

```
error TS2339: Property 'time' does not exist on type 
'_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "linear"; } & CartesianScaleOptions & { beginAtZero: boolean; suggestedMin?: number; suggestedMax?: number; grace?: string | number; ticks: { format: NumberFormatOptions; precision: number; stepSize: number; count: number; }; }> | _DeepPartialObject<...> | _DeepPartialObject<...> | _DeepPa...'.
```

When I first came across this issue, I thought it had something to do with `ng2-charts` library, but even without using this library I get the same error. Below is a small code snippet which results in the error.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartConfiguration } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'daily-chart',
  templateUrl: './daily-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./daily-chart.component.scss']
})
export class DailyChartComponent implements OnInit {
  chartConfig: ChartConfiguration<'line'> = {
    data: {
      datasets: []
    },
    type: 'line',
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'day',
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartConfig.options.scales.x.time.unit = 'week'; // <--- This line results in the error
  }
}
```

I'm using the following libraries:

- `chart.js`: 3.8.0
- `ng2-charts`: 3.0.11
- `angular`: 13.3.5
- `tslib`: 2.4.0
- `typescript`: 4.6.4
- `chartjs-adapter-moment`: 1.0.0,
- `chartjs-plugin-annotation`: 1.4.0,
- `chartjs-plugin-datalabels`: 2.0.0,

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution because it uses a cast to `any` but as a quick fix, you can try the following:

```
import { ChartConfiguration, TimeScaleOptions } from 'chart.js';

...

ngOnInit() {
  const xScaleOptions: TimeScaleOptions = <any>this.chartConfig.options.scales.x;
  xScaleOptions.time.unit = 'week';
}
```